# How to add 2 instances of 2 different classes

Tags: python

Created two instances of different classes. On which way i can add them

```
class Dollar():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
class Euro():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value


d = Dollar(80)
s = Euro(50)

print(d + s)
```

Comment: You should write `__add__` function for these two classes , it means you have your own type of add for your classes.

Comment: And also implement `__str__` to make `print` work correctly